# Make Bitbucket pipeline use new package.json version after running npm version patch

Tags: package.json, bitbucket-pipelines, stenciljs

I have a Bitbucket pipeline, for a StencilJs project which has a first step where i bump the version number in package.json using `npm version patch`. This works fine, and i get it pushed back to the repository and all, without problems. Next step in the pipeline, is where i build the StencilJs project. The problem here is that the project is built using the *old* version number, not the one i bumped it to. So the original version in package.json may be 1.0.3. Step one bumps the version to 1.0.4 and pushes it to repository. I want the next step to build the components using version 1.0.4, but it doesn't. It still uses 1.0.3 when building.

Anyone how knows how i can make the build come out with version 1.0.4?

Kind regards,
Lars

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by putting `npm version patch` into the same step as where i am doing the build.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that your pipeline keeps running on the commit prior to you tagging and committing back. You could set up another pipeline to do the Stencil build that triggers when a new tag is created.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid infinite loop i had to add [skip-ci] in the version patch commit message
My pipeline look like this:

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: Patch version
          script:
            - 'v=$(npm version -m "%s [skip ci]" patch)'
            - 'git push origin ${v}'
            - 'git push'
```